# Update PXSelect BQL for the Sales order page

Tags: acumatica

I want to add an extra "where" clause to the View that is used in Sales Orders
I need to only show the records that the logged-in user created.

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    [PXViewName(Messages.SOOrder)]
    public PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
             LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, 
                                Equal<SOOrder.customerID>>>,
             Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>,
               And<Where<Customer.bAccountID, IsNull, Or<Match<Customer, 
              Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>,
//beblow is give problems 
                And<Where<SOOrder.owner, Equal<AccessInfo.userName>>>   >> 
   Documents;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is older code to limit users of a given Role, which makes use of 
SOOrder.CreatedByID and Users.pkID.

First, a Users view is added to establish Users cache:

```
    public PXSelectJoin<Users,
                        InnerJoin<UsersInRoles,
                            On<Users.username, Equal<UsersInRoles.username>>,
                        InnerJoin<Roles,
                            On<Roles.rolename, Equal<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>>,
                        Where<Users.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>
                           , And<Roles.rolename, Equal<fieldSales>>>> salesUser;
```

Second, the Users can be added to BQL of the OrderNbr listing as follows:

```
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [OrderNbr(typeof(Search2<SOOrder.orderNbr,
        LeftJoinSingleTable<BAccount, On<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>>,
        Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>>,
        And<Where<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNull,
                Or<SOOrder.createdByID, Equal<Current<Users.pKID>>>>>>,
        OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>), Filterable = true)]
    [SO.Numbering()]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_OrderNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

In our case, we needed to limit the OrderType choices for this Role:

```
    //protected String _OrderType;
    [PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, InputMask = ">aa")]
    [PXDefault(SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder, typeof(SOSetup.defaultOrderType))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search5<SOOrderType.orderType,
        InnerJoin<SOOrderTypeOperation, On<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType,
            Equal<SOOrderType.orderType>, And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, Equal<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>,
        LeftJoin<SOSetupApproval, On<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<SOSetupApproval.orderType>>
            , InnerJoin<Users, On<Current<AccessInfo.userName>, Equal<Users.username>>
            , InnerJoin<UsersInRoles, On<Users.username, Equal<UsersInRoles.username>>
            , InnerJoin<Roles, On<Roles.rolename, Equal<UsersInRoles.rolename>>>>>>>,
         Where2<Where<Roles.guest, Equal<False>>,
                Or<Where<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<string_FT>,
                        Or<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<string_TR>>>>>,
        Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderType.orderType>>>))]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderTypeOperation.iNDocType, NotEqual<INTranType.transfer>,
        Or<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.warehouse>>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.requireAllocation, NotEqual<True>,
        Or<AllocationAllowed>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.active, Equal<True>>), null)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_OrderType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

The OrderNbr listing can be limited by the Users cache, those Users in the given Role. Users 
not in the Role can see all Orders:

```
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [OrderNbrRep(typeof(Search2<SOOrder.orderNbr,
        LeftJoinSingleTable<BAccount, On<SOOrder.customerID, Equal<BAccount.bAccountID>>>,
        Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>>,
        And<Where<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNull,
                Or<SOOrder.createdByID, Equal<Current<Users.pKID>>>>>>,
        OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>), Filterable = true)]
    [SO.Numbering()]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_OrderNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

In our case, the Customer listing needed to be limited to prevent sales reps from 
viewing/using unrelated customers:

```
    [PXDefault]
    [CustomerRep(typeof(Where2<Where2<Where<Customer.type, IsNotNull,
                                       And<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, NotEqual<string_FT>,
                                            Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, Equal<string_FT>,
                                                And<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNull>>>>>,
                                    Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.aRDocType>, Equal<ARDocType.noUpdate>,
                                        Or<Customer.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>>>>>,
                            Or<Where<Current<SOOrder.orderType>, Equal<string_FT>,
                                        And<SalesPerson.salesPersonID, Equal<EPEmployee.salesPersonID>,
                                        And<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNotNull>>>>>),

        Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), Filterable = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

The custom attributes (OrderNbrRep and CustomerRep) classes are shown below, perhaps 
they can be of use to you for ideas:

```
public sealed class OrderNbrRepAttribute : PXSelectorAttribute
{
    public OrderNbrRepAttribute(Type SearchType)
        : base(SearchType,
        typeof(SOOrder.orderNbr),
        typeof(SOOrder.customerOrderNbr),
        typeof(SOOrder.orderDate),
        typeof(SOOrder.customerID),
        typeof(BAccount.acctName),
        typeof(SOOrder.customerLocationID),
        typeof(SOOrder.curyID),
        typeof(SOOrder.curyOrderTotal),
        typeof(SOOrder.status),
        typeof(SOOrder.invoiceNbr))
    {
    }
}


[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Customer.status, IsNull,
                    Or<Customer.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>,
                    Or<Customer.status, Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>),
                            PX.Objects.AR.Messages.CustomerIsInStatus, typeof(Customer.status))]
public sealed class CustomerRepAttribute : AcctSubAttribute
{
    public const string DimensionName = "CUSTOMER";

    public CustomerRepAttribute(Type WhereType)
    {
        Type cmd = BqlCommand.Compose(
                        typeof(Search5<,,,,>),
                        typeof(BAccountR.bAccountID),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Customer),
                        typeof(On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(CustSalesPeople),
                        typeof(On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<CustSalesPeople.bAccountID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(SalesPerson),
                        typeof(On<CustSalesPeople.salesPersonID, Equal<SalesPerson.salesPersonID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(EPEmployee),
                        typeof(On<Optional<AccessInfo.userID>, Equal<EPEmployee.userID>>),

                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Contact),
                        typeof(On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccountR.defContactID>>>),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,,>),
                        typeof(Address),
                        typeof(On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Address.addressID, Equal<BAccountR.defAddressID>>>),
                        typeof(LeftJoin<,>),
                        typeof(Location),
                        typeof(On<Location.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>, And<Location.locationID, Equal<BAccountR.defLocationID>>>),
                        //typeof(Where<Customer.bAccountID, IsNotNull>),
                        WhereType,
                        typeof(Aggregate<GroupBy<BAccountR.bAccountID, GroupBy<BAccountR.acctCD, GroupBy<Customer.acctName>>>>),
                        typeof(OrderBy<Asc<BAccountR.acctCD>>)

                        );

        PXDimensionSelectorAttribute attr;
        _Attributes.Add(attr = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(DimensionName, cmd, typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
            typeof(BAccountR.acctCD), typeof(Customer.acctName), typeof(Customer.customerClassID),
            typeof(Customer.status), typeof(Contact.phone1), typeof(Address.city), typeof(Address.countryID)
        ));
        attr.DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName);
        attr.CacheGlobal = true;
        attr.FilterEntity = typeof(Customer);
        _SelAttrIndex = _Attributes.Count - 1;
        this.Filterable = true;

    }
}
```

Finally, in our case the SalesOrder View was handled with a delegate as shown below:

```
    protected string _orderNbrNext = null; 

    [PXViewName(PX.Objects.SO.Messages.SOOrder)]
    public PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
        LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<SOOrder.customerID>>>,
        Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>>,
            And<Where<Optional<AccessInfo.userID>, Equal<SOOrder.createdByID>,
                Or<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>,
        OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>> Document;  // handles mobile listing      

    protected virtual IEnumerable document()
    {
        Users us = null;
        if (this.salesUser.Current == null)
            us = this.salesUser.Select();
        if (us != null)
            this.salesUser.Current = us;

        // Handle limit to listings, (FIELDSALES impl).
        PXSelectBase<SOOrder> cmd = new PXSelectJoin<SOOrder,
                                        LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<SOOrder.customerID>>>,
                                        Where2<Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderType>>>,
                                            And<Where2<Where<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNotNull,
                                                And<Optional<AccessInfo.userID>, Equal<SOOrder.createdByID>>>,                                                   
                                                Or<Where<Current<Users.pKID>, IsNull,
                                                And<Optional<AccessInfo.userID>, Equal<SOOrder.createdByID>,
                                                And<DateDiff<SOOrder.createdDateTime, Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>, day>, LessEqual<int_One>,
                                                Or<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Optional<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>>>>>>,
                                        OrderBy<Desc<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>(Base);

        List<object> parms = new List<object>();

        parms.Add(Base.soordertype.Current.OrderType);

        parms.Add(Base.Accessinfo.UserID);  // order listing limited to logon (Rep) user
        parms.Add(Base.Accessinfo.UserID);  // order listing limited to logon (internal) user
        if (_orderNbrNext != null)
            parms.Add(_orderNbrNext);

        foreach (PXResult<SOOrder, Customer> res in cmd.Select(parms.ToArray()))
        {
            SOOrder order = (SOOrder)res;
            if (PXContext.PXIdentity.User.IsInRole("FIELDSALES"))
            {
                if (order.CreatedByID != Base.Accessinfo.UserID)
                    continue;
            }

            // ensure SO behaviour?
            if (Base.IsMobile == true && order.OrderType == "TR")
            order.Behavior = "SO";

            yield return res;
        }
    }
```